# Event not triggering in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I am having an issue where clicking `#target3` does not trigger the event handler. I *think* the issue is that the event is not propagating down to the `<option>` of the `<select>` element? The annoyance is that this snippet works in; IE8 and above, and Firefox, but does not work in Chrome?

```js
var target = 1;

$("#target"+target).bind("click.clickEvent",function(){TargetClicked(this)});

function TargetClicked(ele)
{
    if($(ele).prop("id") == ("target" + target))
    {
       $("body").append("You clicked >> #" + $(ele).prop("id") + "<br>");
       $(ele).unbind(".clickEvent");
       target++;
       $("#target"+target).bind("click.clickEvent",function(){TargetClicked(this)});
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="target1">Click here first</p>
<p>
  <select id="target2">
    <option>----</option>
    <option id="target3">target 3</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

This is from a very large project, so I would like to try and find a `javascript / JQuery` fix or workaround for this issue if possible as editing the `HTML` is not feasible.

Comment: Instead of a `click` event, you could bind an event handler to the `<select>` tag's `change` event.  Then in your callback function you could evaluate whether the option with the `id` property of `select3` is selected, and act accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known Chrome bug

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=26017

I fixed this issue by checking to see what type of element was being targeted, and then in the case of an `<option>`, I instead applied a `change` event instead of a `click` event.

The caveat is that this event has to go on the `<select>` element, not the `<option>` element, which in my case was not ideal.

```
if(!$("#target"+target).is("option"))
    $("#target"+target).click(function(){TargetClicked(this)});
else
    $("#target"+target).parent("select").change(function(){TargetClicked(this)});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `this` to the new event, which is `window`. Instead pass `$("#target"+target)`.

Note, workaround. To return expected result at chrome, you can use `change` event, `.is()`, `select.options.selectedIndex`, `.eq()`

```js
var target = 1;

$("#target"+target)
.bind("click.clickEvent change.clickEvent",function() {
  TargetClicked(this)
});

function TargetClicked(ele) {
    if ($(ele).prop("id") == ("target" + target)) {
       $("body").append("You clicked >> #" 
                        + $(ele).prop("id") + "<br>"
                        + ($(ele).is("select") 
                         ? "You clicked >> #" 
                           + $("option")
                             .eq(ele[0].options.selectedIndex)
                             .prop("id")
                         : "")
                        );
       $(ele).unbind(".clickEvent");
       target++;
       $("#target"+target)
       .bind("click.clickEvent change.clickEvent",function(e) {
         TargetClicked($("#target"+target))
       });
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<p id="target1">Click here first</p>
<p>
  <select id="target2">
    <option>----</option>
    <option id="target3">target 3</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xy5rc1tu/1/

Comment: Thanks for the post, however this snippet still doesn't work in chrome for me. I only get: `You clicked >> #target1
You clicked >> #target2`

Comment: Are you trying to create an element and add `click` event to new element?

Comment: My goal is to trigger the `TargetClicked` event when `#target3` is clicked. I am only creating an element for debug atm instead of `console.log`.

Comment: _"My goal is to trigger the TargetClicked event when `#target3` is clicked."_ `TargetClicked` is called when `#target3` is clicked

Comment: It doesn't fire in chrome - latest version.?

Comment: Result at chromium 51 is `You clicked >> #target1`, `You clicked >> #target2`. You can determine version of chrome you are using by visiting `chrome://version`

Comment: Result in Firefox and IE8 and above: `You clicked >> #target1`, `You clicked >> #target2`,  `You clicked >> #target3`

Comment: Are you trying to attach `click` event to `<option>` element?

Comment: Yes I am. Is this not possible in Chrome?

Comment: Though you can use `change` event to select the currently selected `<option>` element

Comment: This is what I feared. How infuriating. Yes I think I am going to have to go with that approach, just requies a **LOT** more reconfiguration of code...

Comment: If you are trying to attach `click` event to `<option>` element, why do you expect `#target2` `select` element to be appended to results?

Comment: I am creating a linear software walkthrough, and when you click on various elements, you get information. So that is why there are click events on different element types. p.s. I think this is what you were asking but not 100%. :)

Comment: There is a possible workaround for chrome, where `#target2`, `#target3` are appended at same event

Comment: @Zze Approach using `.is()`, `select.options.selectedIndex` , `.eq()` https://jsfiddle.net/xy5rc1tu/1/

Comment: Thanks for all of the suggestions, I will have to investigate these options.